# Font Awesome 5: Differences fa-svg-with-js.css / fontawesome.min.js / fontawesome-all.min.js

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I've read the official documentation but I didn't get much information regarding `fa-svg-with-js.css`

Currently, I'm using `fontawesome-all.min.js` and that's all I need to get going. However, the file size is ridiculously big (680kb).

I noticed there was another folder with a file named `fa-svg-with-js.`css what is this for? Do I need it?

I also notice there's another file called `fontawesome.min.js` with a much smaller file size (27kb). How do I use this and why is it smaller than the svg one.

I don't want to use the webfont version. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use any text editor to look at those files - they're all text files, albeit minimised. fontawesome-all.min.js does contain the icons themselves (in svg format), fa-svg-with-js.css does not (so you will need a separate font file). What more info do you need?

Comment: I need to know which one to include. My aim was to be able to use all icons without having to load that heavy `fontawesome-all.min.js` but I'm not sure which one. For example, do I need both css and js or just the css or just the js? I looked at those files but still confuse. Let's say  if I load `fontawesome.min.js` do I need to load the css or fonts as well? There's no clear indication about this in their documentation. Thanks!